# C# add Code to an Method at Runtime or with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

for my Logging Lib i´m planning to develop a few Features. The first one will Log the called Method and it´s Parameters. For Example

```
public void DoSomething(int value) 
{
    try
    {
        // Exception is thrown
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.Error(ex);
    }
}
```

The Logger should now log: Error in Method DoSomething in class xy Paramter value = 15.
It´s not possible with Reflection and with the StackFrame i can get the Method Name and the Parameter Names but not the Parameter value.
My Idea was now to Inject Code to this Method at runtime or after Compile Time.
I tried it with Mono.Cecil so i injected Code to this Method which passed the Name of the paramter and the value of it to my logger. That is working.

The Second idea is to Add a Stopwatch to the Method:

```
[AnalyzePerformanceOfMethod]
public int DoSomething(int value) 
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    try
    {
        // code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    watch.Stop();
    _logger.Write("Method took: " + watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    return 10;
}
```

My Idea was also to add this code with Mono.Cecil. (The code should only be added if the Attribut is defined above the Method).
That works for Methods with Type void. But if i have a Method which Returns something. I think i will get Problems becouse i add code and so manipulate the Stack. And the return values are stored in the statck as far is a i know.

Is there another way i can go?
Cecil only works with not loaded Assemblys. Is there a way to add this code at runtime to the Methods which has this Attribute defined?
If there is no other way, how can i add Code at the End of a Method or Function with cecil?

Comment: What about PostSharp? https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: If the only missing things are parameters value why not pass it to your logger ? `void Logger.Error(Exception ex, params object[] methodParams);` Seems much more simple to me.

Comment: @IronSlug you are right. That is much more simple, but i know if i use this lib in my Company more than half of the developers will not Log that Parameters. So i try to create a lib which is doing that automatically.

Comment: @Alex Well I guess your best shot is the [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), if your company policy allows it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try approach with loading small interface based plugins at runtime. You could then load as many implementations as you want and even generate new C# code (implementations) on the fly. On the fly you can generate code using reflection or even by writing plain text into file and then compiling it using cs.exe.

You can check the following articles:

[Working with the C# 2.0 Command Line Compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Compiling C# Code at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime)

[Dynamic Load .NET Assembly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/666492/Dynamic-Load-NET-Assembly)